# FATAL EXCEPTION: main?

Tags: flutter, dart

when I run my flutter app I get the Following Error, I don't know what happens on my code?

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G530H in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
E/AndroidRuntime(27721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(27721): Process: com.example.save_geez_learning_aid, PID: 27721
E/AndroidRuntime(27721): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.save_geez_learning_aid/com.example.save_geez_learning_aid.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable

```
E/AndroidRuntime(27721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(27721): Process: com.example.save_geez_learning_aid, PID: 27721
E/AndroidRuntime(27721): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.save_geez_learning_aid/com.example.save_geez_learning_aid.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040015
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2721)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040015
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2890)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2765)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:978)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.getSplashScreenFromManifest(FlutterActivity.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.provideSplashScreen(FlutterActivity.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:301)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:518)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6112)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1117)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(27721): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:202)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:147)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1095)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1017)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2880)
E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    ... 21 more
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:57907/rMK1eOGGOzQ=/
```

Comment: ``res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml`` file not found as it says. Check if the specified file exists or not !!

Answer (score 0):

You may have delete the `launch_background.xml` file in `android/app/src/main/res/drawable`.

My guess comes from your error, specifically this:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040015
```

Comment: @beby You can either recreate your file by hand. (this is the content of the file -> https://pastebin.com/UNeUCBXN

Or you can also recreate the android folder of your flutter app by deleting it and use the command `flutter create .` inside your project folder.